# sending JSON as string issue

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I try to send to WCF server a property of type 'string'
the string will contain a json, but i always get this error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type XX.XX Encountered unexpected character '''.'. See server logs for more details.

I run a JSON.Stringfy(json) method before is send it to the server,
the json looks like this for example:

```
{
 "JsonString": "{"Wontext":{"StorageUniqueId":"0","FormName":"Form_1","FormVersion":"1.0"}}"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As the error tells you, the json contains unexpected quotes. Just remove them:

```
{ "JsonString": { "Wontext": { "StorageUniqueId": "0", "FormName": "Form_1", "FormVersion": "1.0" } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked:

"JsonString": "{\"Context\":{\"StorageUniqueId\":\"0\",\"FormName\":\"Form_1\",\"FormVersion\":\"1.0\"},\"JsonData\":{\"Name\":\"SRS\",\"Disease\":{\"Name\":\"Sick\",\"Location\":\"Left Hand\"},\"bla bla\":\" bla blaaa\"}}}"